# Centered text, aligned left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

This is probably a rather trivial question, but I don't see an obvious way on how to solve it. I want to center a piece of text, but i want to have the centered text be aligned left.

So I would like:

```
\begin{center}
line1
line2
line3
\end{center}
```

but where line1, line2 and line3 are aligned left, but still are centered.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use the whole width of a line? `␣␣␣␣␣text␣␣␣␣␣`

Comment: Do you mean the whole body is aligned left but individual lines are centered among themselves? It is not very clear what you are asking for. Do you think you can show a simulated output?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is: I want to center the block of lines, but I want align the lines to the left of that centered block (i.e. I want to let all the lines start at the same point).

Comment: Well then use a minipage `\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}<content>\end{minipage}\end{center}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a tabular which aligns the text to the left and is itself centered in the text. This could look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    This is line 1 with some text. \\
    This is line 2 with a slightly different text \\
    Line 3 is completely different and also a bit longer. \\
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This solution is fine, only when the lines are rather short. If one of the lines is v-e-r-y long, this it won't do the job.

Comment: Thats right. You could use a table with fixed width, but these are centered, if I remember correct.

Comment: Define a new coloumntype with the ragged2e package and the definition of \newcolumntype{A}{>{\RaggedRight}p{1\textwidth}} and you have a defined width with left aligned text. But seriously, doing it with a minipage and maybe \hfill{} is better.

Answer (score 7):

Using a `minipage` is rather simple and can be helpful in this case.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \lipsum[2]

    \begin{itemize}
    \item This is line 1 with some text.
    \item This is line 2 with a slightly different text
    \item Line 3 is completely different and also a bit longer.
    \item And what about really really really really really
      really really really really really really really really really
      really lines?
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the itemize environment? Works without it and a parskip too and i guess that is what he searched for.

Comment: @JohannesO: Just for the sake of demonstration. It seemed like the OP referred to a list which is centered and indented. You could tweak the `itemize` environment as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a centered `tabulary` environment:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}L@{}}
      This is line 1 with some text. \\
      This is line 2 with a slightly different text. \\
      Line 3 is completely different and also a bit longer.
    \end{tabulary}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]