# Center memoir chapter precis if not full width

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir

I would like to have each chapter precis be ragged right, but would like the text block itself to be centered. So, a short chapter precis would appear to be centered, but as soon as the lines start wrapping, then it would become clear that the text is actually ragged right.

Apart from that, I'm quite content with the look of `memoir`'s chapter precises and for full-length chapter precises, I would like for them to look exactly alike.

My first thought has been to [use a centered `tabulary` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694830/71332), but I can't seem to get it to compile.

## Attempt 1

```tex
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\chapterstyle{dash}
\renewcommand{\prechapterprecis}{%
  \vspace*{\prechapterprecisshift}%
  \begingroup\centering\precisfont\begin{tabulary}{0.75\linewidth}{@{}L@{}}}
\renewcommand{\postchapterprecis}{\end{tabulary}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \chapterprecishere{
    A short text
  }
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \chapterprecishere{
    A longer text that should be long enough to wrap and to ensure that it keeps going a little bit
  }
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

## Attempt 2

```tex
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\chapterstyle{dash}
\renewcommand{\chapterprecishere}[1]{%
  \vspace*{\prechapterprecisshift}%
  \begingroup\centering\precisfont\begin{tabulary}{0.75\linewidth}{@{}L@{}}}%
  #1\end{tabulary}\endgroup%
}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \chapterprecishere{
    A short text
  }
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \chapterprecishere{
    A longer text that should be long enough to wrap and to ensure that it keeps going a little bit
  }
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `varwidth` package which allows you to set text in a box that matches its natural width up to a preset maximum. Here's a version that does what you want.

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\chapterstyle{dash}
\renewcommand{\prechapterprecis}{%
  \vspace*{\prechapterprecisshift}%
  \begin{quote}%
  \centering%
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
  %Uncomment the next line if you have multiple paragraphs
  %in the precis
  %\parskip\parsep% 
  \precisfont}
\renewcommand{\postchapterprecis}{\end{varwidth}\end{quote}}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \chapterprecishere{
    A short text
  }
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \chapterprecishere{
    A longer text that should be long enough to wrap and to ensure that it keeps going a little bit
  }
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter 1 image]
[image: chapter 2 image]

Comment: This looks really good, but with this solution the chapters’ first paragraph is indented… Is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: @FredrikP I've updated the answer. Looking back at the `memoir` original definitions, it uses the `quote` environment, so we can just insert the `varwidth` box + `\centering` inside that.

Comment: Good idea! It fixed having to copy the width of the `quote` environment by some other means. However, it didn't solve the indent in the first paragraph. I've suggested an edit that fixes this (by adding `\usepackage{noindentafter}` and `\NoIndentAfterCmd{\chapterprecishere}` in the preamble). The only remaining issue I can see is that the `varwidth` environment seems to have a different the vertical space between paragraphs (`\parskip`?) than the `quote` environment. (Admittedly, it wasn't clear that this was needed in my example code.)

Comment: I added a fix to the vertical space between paragraphs in my edit

Comment: The code I posted did not have an indent before the first paragraph, so your indent fix is not needed. The `varwidth` package does nothing with the value of `\parskip`.

Comment: @FredrikP I've removed the `indentfirst` code, which isn't needed (if your actual document needs it then there's something else going on). I've also commented out the spacing code which seems very particular to your needs and wasn't part of the question anyway. This way the answer might be useful more generally.

Comment: You're correct about the indent. It appeared when I added an empty line between the chapter precis and the first paragraph. I presume that you are correct about the `\parskip` as well. But if you have a chapter precis with two paragraphs and add a `quote` environment with the exact same content, then you will see that the interparagraph space is different. I'm guessing that it has to do with `quote` being based on a list, which `varwidth` (presumably) isn't...

Comment: Seem like a good decision. If someone else needs my edits, then I guess this conversation will lead them to check the edits of your answer :-)

Comment: @FredrikP Yes, I think that's right. I hadn't understood what you meant about the parskip because I assumed the precis would not have multiple paragraphs (which `memoir` also assumes it seems.)